# Bash script freezes after x amount of runs

Tags: linux, bash, script, freeze

I have made a script that is testing a webserver with siege. Before each run I want to reset the VM to a snapshot so that each test have the same starting point. The problem is that the script stops working after X runs, sometimes it works for 2 runs and sometimes 7.
This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..30}
do
        ssh root@10.204.15.168 vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.revert 1 9 0
        sleep 2m
        siege -c 1000 -t 60S http://10.204.15.165:80/ &> /root/512/test$i
done
```

It looks like the siege test is running in the last run but the script cant execute the ssh command next time. The host at 10.204.15.168 is a ESXi machine that has a public ssh key from the host that runs the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to ssh inside loop.
If you want to use ssh inside the loop add a '***-n***' to it, so that it works for each iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..30}
do
    ssh -n root@10.204.15.168 vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.revert 1 9 0
    sleep 2m
    siege -c 1000 -t 60S http://10.204.15.165:80/ &> /root/512/test$i
done
```